# AngularJS - accessing directive scope

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

So, I'm looking to use `ui.bootstrap.tooltip` to appear when an element in a form is invalid.

I'm using a directive to do this - it's a bit ugly, but it works. Except for one thing - the controller isn't seeing the updated model values due to another scope being created in the directive.

I can get the model value through the form and using `$viewValue`, but this seems a bit "unclean" to me.

Also, is there a better way to get the "tooltip element", that I'm using `elem.parent().children()[2];` for? I suppose I could create a `<template>` in the directive for all this.

The JSFiddle is at: http://jsfiddle.net/n8vNw/2/

Comment: Have you check existing bootstrap tooltip implementation with angular ? https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js

Comment: I am already using that tooltip. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't have a useable API, so I activate it using jQuery and trigger().

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651227/enable-angular-ui-tooltip-on-custom-events

Answer (score 1):

You have created a parser function but never return a value from it. A parser function is used to parse the input value before it ends up in your model. Since a value never is returned, `$scope.email` will always be undefined.

Secondly there's no reason for your directive to create an isolated scope since you don't use that anyway, unless you're not showing us all the code--in such case us the `$parse` service instead.

Regarding how you access the tooltip element, perhaps let your `formTooltipError` directive create and add the element using the `$compile` service. (I haven't used Angular Bootstrap so there might be an easier/better answer.)

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8vNw/5/).

Comment: There isn't a need for an isolated scope, but my understanding was that one was created when I included ngModel in the directive. Thanks!