# Adding Angular Bootstrap Tooltip dynamically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, tooltip

Is there any way to add [Angular Tooltips](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/tooltip) dynamically from within the controller?  I tried setting the attributes from the controller which does not work.

```
$("#test").attr("bs-tooltip", "content");
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651227/enable-angular-ui-tooltip-on-custom-events

Answer (score 4):

Does it need to be an angular-strap tooltip, or can you just use bootstrap itself? Something like

```
$("#test").tooltip({
    title: 'content',
    trigger: 'hover',
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Seems better than adding directives after compilation...if you do need to do it from a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Angular-Strap won't show the tooltip if the text is "", so if you know you will need or might want a tooltip, you could start with the text being "" and dynamically change it.

Alternatively, the documentation claims:

> Both $scope.show() and $scope.hide() are available inside the tooltip to toggle its visibility.

Although its not clear to me how to use this functionality.