# single popover ui angular bootstrap

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I have been using *Angular-UI Bootstrap* popover for my project. I have multiple popovers in a view.

The functionality required was to have a single popover open at a time. I could have used "focus" as my trigger. But using it will close the popover if I click on the content of the popover.

I have been able to achieve this programmatically by following [@Kim Ras solution in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23377441/2106516)

But the problem is  that I am able to close the popover only when clicking popover button. 
What I want, is, to be closed if I click anywhere on the page other than the popover content.

Comment: Could you provide what you have done so far?