# Angular UI Bootstrap Popover: trigger manually

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to use the [Angular UI Bootstrap Popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover).

The documentation states, that the trigger can be either *mouseenter*, *click* or *focus*. In my situation I would like to show the popover on a input-field if a back end calculation fails. How can I trigger the popover to show in code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good way to dynamically open / close a popover (or tooltip) using angular, based on expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939754/good-way-to-dynamically-open-close-a-popover-or-tooltip-using-angular-based)

Comment: This was already asked many times on SO. Today I just published a directive that allows the manual control of popovers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31372487/190438

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the click event (or other based on your config) with `$("#btn-id").click()`

Comment: ^ Except please don't use jquery $.

Comment: You can also trigger with angular way:  angular.element('#btn-id').trigger('click');

Comment: It this really the best solution? Using this approach, the uses will dismiss the popover, when clicking the input field again, right?

Comment: The popup will be triggered with click event, so I think this is the most easy way.For ui-bootstrap, the popup div is generated when you click(or hover) the directive, so you can not control the popup div with something like ng-show.