# Angularjs validation using popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I saw this [bootstrap popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) and I'am trying to use it in my project.

Consider a simple example.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="data" step="0.1" />
```

The input field has steps of 0.1. I want the user to enter only values up to 10 and not beyond that.

If user enters anything beyond 10, I want a popover to display at the top stating that the value needs to be entered from the range 0 to 10 only.

How can I achieve this? The popover shown above does not have any example similar to the one I am looking for. Can someone shed some light?

Comment: `max="10"` ?  Then hook validation state changes to trigger popover, as `class="ng-invalid"` should be set.  See docs at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms section "Custom Validation" ?

Comment: See also https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange `<input ... ng-change="myFunc()"/>` to hook your jquery code to check `class="..."` contents and/or check AngularJS validation properties, to decide to popover (or remove the popover).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adapt the programmatically triggering popups answer (or any of the directives from [Good way to dynamically open / close a popover (or tooltip) using angular, based on expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939754) and tie it to the field validation

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input popover="Should be between 1 and 10" name="myInput" ng-model="test"
        popover-toggle="myForm.myInput.$error.max" max="10" type="number" 
        popover-placement="bottom" />
</form>
```

I've used the directive from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31372487/360067

---

Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/2uk4YM5zinM01ayzZKdd?p=preview

Comment: @potatopeelings- one small question. can i not have it without the form ? what should be done in case i want to use it without form?

Comment: @potatopeelings- it only takes number as input. a rare case is that it take character 'e' too. how to exclude 'e' from being accepted ? e is the eulers number and thats y it is accepting it. how can i avoid thaT ?

Comment: Yeah, you can pass any expression to `popover-toggle` (like write your own expression to verify the value). The e is because its treated as an exponential number - once you take the form off, you'll have to write your own number validation and you can exclude e in addition to the invalid range values)